# What type of chart would you choose for this requirement in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I have a requirement, below I have posted as screen shot.

Here is my screen shot

[image]

Comment: You should include the question text directly, not as an image

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the ***Smooth Line With Markers*** or ***Line With Markers*** chart type, after you drag and drop chart, you will see it:

[image]

Then you will have a chart like this:

[image]

Comment: can we do multiple series line chart because in above screen shot only 2 series i.e. initial and quantity

Comment: @Himansu - Yes sure, This is just an example you can do multiple series.